# One query with subquery that uses data of the main one

Tags: sql, mariadb

| id | lft | rgt | company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 12 | 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 13 | 8 | 9 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 14 | 3 | 4 | 2 |

I want to write a query that gets e.g. the row with 10 + row 11/12 based on the other columns of the first row. Think my example query might make more sense.

```
SELECT * FROM organisation o 
WHERE o.id = 10 and o.company = 1
OR o.id IN (SELECT id FROM organisation WHERE lft > o.lft AND lft < o.rgt and company = 1);
```

Is this possible in 1 query. Or do I first get row 10, then do another query to get the other 2 rows based on the lft/rgt values.

What I want is get row `10` or rows where `lft` is between `lft` and `rgt` from the row(s) that I want.

But if I try this then I only get row with id 10.

***lft is only unique per company, so not unique for the entire table***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with two queries, one to get the row with `id = 10` and one to get the other rows which meet your condition, using a `JOIN` to evaluate the condition. We can `UNION` the two queries together to get all the results in one query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM organisation o 
WHERE o.id = 10
UNION ALL
SELECT o2.*
FROM organisation o
JOIN organisation o2 ON o2.lft > o.lft AND o2.lft < o.rgt
WHERE o.id = 10
```

Output:

```
id  lft     rgt
10  1       7
11  2       3
12  5       6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a5zNBfstmsHTC316HrkAbJ/0)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use self join to get result.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT o2.* 
FROM organisation o 
INNER JOIN organisation o2
  ON (o2.lft > o.lft AND o2.lft < o.rgt) OR o2.id = o.id
WHERE o.id = 10  and o.company = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdc401f/1/0)**:

```
| id | lft | rgt | company |
|----|-----|-----|---------|
| 10 |   1 |   7 |       1 |
| 11 |   2 |   3 |       1 |
| 12 |   5 |   6 |       1 |
```

Comment: had to add `AND o2.company = 1` to the ON clause, but then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If your bounds are *inclusive*, then you can simply do:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM organisation o 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM organisation o2
              WHERE o2.id = 10 AND o2.company = 1 AND
                    o2.lft <= o.lft AND
                    o2.rgt >= o.rgt
             );
```

If the bounds are exclusive, then you need a second explicit comparison, because the row does not match itself:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM organisation o 
WHERE o.id = 10 AND o2.company = 1 OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM organisation o2
              WHERE o2.id = 10 AND o2.company = 1 AND
                    o2.lft < o.lft AND
                    o2.rgt > o.rgt
             );
```